# When using the GA4 Data API I get a different value for total sessions if I break it down by session source and sum compared to just querying sessions

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

If I just query the API for total sessions without any other dimensions I get a different value then if I add the sessionSource dimension and sum the sessions.

I have checked all of my filters and they match for both queries and the sessions are under the 500,000 amount that might be impacted by sampling

Comment: please edit your question and include [example]

Answer (score 0):

This is a well known issue that GA4 metrics have different values for different dimensions. One of the many reasons is data thresholds to avoid leaking personal information: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9383630